# The method findElements(By) is not applicable for the arguments (MobileElement)

Tags: java, android, mobile, find, appium

```
MobileElement followButton = (MobileElement) driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.ListView[@index='0']//android.widget.FrameLayout[@index='"+loopVal+"']//android.widget.LinearLayout[@index='0']//android.widget.FrameLayout[@index='2']//android.widget.TextView[@index='0']"));

    if(driver.findElements(followButton).isEmpty()) {

    //do something

    }
```

at `findElements` it gives me an error that says

> The method findElements(By) is not applicable for the arguments (MobileElement)

so i tried re-organizing this method into a try-catch

```
try {

    MobileElement followButton = (MobileElement) driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.ListView[@index='0']//android.widget.FrameLayout[@index='"+loopVal+"']//android.widget.LinearLayout[@index='0']//android.widget.FrameLayout[@index='2']//android.widget.TextView[@index='0']"));

    } catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e) {

        //do something

    }
```

but the new error is now that when i try to `.getText();` of `followButton`

```
String followOrNot = followButton.getText();
```

it gives me an error that says

> followButton cannot be resolved

basically what i am trying to do is find `followButton` and run `.getText()` but if `followButton` is not found, perform an operation to handle the error

can anyone help out?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
List<AndroidElement> followButtons = driver.findElements(MobileBy.xpath("//android.widget.ListView[@index='0']//android.widget.FrameLayout[@index='"+loopVal+"']//android.widget.LinearLayout[@index='0']//android.widget.FrameLayout[@index='2']//android.widget.TextView[@index='0']"));


if(! followButtons.isEmpty()) {

    System.out.println(followButtons.get(0).getText()); // print text

    }
```

**OR**

If you have `id` or `class name` you can use below code too

```
List<MobileElement> elementsOne = (List<MobileElement>) driver.findElementsByAccessibilityId("SomeAccessibilityID");
List<MobileElement> elementsTwo = (List<MobileElement>) driver.findElementsByClassName("SomeClassName");
```

More details is [here](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/element/find-elements/#find-elements)